# Rename Azure Function with Event Hub Trigger

Tags: azure-functions

I have an Azure function with an event hub trigger which was deployed with a typo in the function name. It is a .NET package deployment function.

Events have already been consumed and I want to understand the impact of correcting the function name and redeploying the function code.

Will the checkpointing be maintained for the function / consumer group? Or will renaming the function result in it being recognised as a new function and events re-consumed?

Comment: Do you want to change name of function inside the function app right?

Answer (score 0):

> the impact of correcting the function name and redeploying the function code.

Complete new deployment takes place if you are redeploying from anywhere, due to which before functions will be removed and new deployed functions with modifications will be there.

For example, If you are deploying with VS code you will be shown this dialog box:

[image]

> Or will renaming the function result in it being recognised as a new function and events re-consumed?

AFAIK, No events will be re-consumed or function will not retrigger for previous events, if any new event occurs then it will trigger.